# Where have I gone wrong with this c# simple sql insert

Tags: c#, .net, sql

**Final Note:** After adding the executeNonQuery **AND**  after I changed the connection string from Filename=|DataDirectory|\testconn.mdf to Filename=c:\Documents........\testconn.mdf. My data began to insert into my table.  Thanks all for the help.

While working with this sql insert I find that the code runs without any exceptions but after going to database explorer and looking at the show table data, the data was not inserted.  Originally I wasn’t using the transaction code but read on this site this may be the problem it also runs without an exception but still does not actually insert into the table.  While stepping through I can see where the status changes from open to close following the conn.Open() and connClose() statements. In addition for best practice  is there a cleaner/better way to write my SqlConnection string as well as my SqlCommand strings?  Thank you My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Transactions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CommittableTransaction MASTER_TRANSACTION = new CommittableTransaction();
            // 1. Instantiate the connection
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\testconn.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");


                  try
            {
                // 2. Open the connection
                conn.Open();
                conn.EnlistTransaction(MASTER_TRANSACTION);

                // 3. Pass the connection to a command object
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Client_Master(Client_ID, Client_First, Client_Last) VALUES('2', 'Joe', 'Shmoe')", conn);
                MASTER_TRANSACTION.Commit();

            }
            finally
            {

             conn.Close();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the schema of `Client_Master`?

Answer (score 3):

try calling

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

before  `MASTER_TRANSACTION.Commit();`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to call an execute method on the the [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) object.

Answer (score 1):

you need to execute the command via `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` to execute the SQL command

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, execute the cmd and then right before the line with "finally" add:

```
 catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

and it will show other exceptions if any.

And you don't really need the overhead of a transaction for a single insert.... and if you did you should have a rollback in the Exception block.

Comment: Thank you I made those changes as suggested. Still no visible insert into the table but if I try to do it again I get thrown a primary key exception, any thoughts?

Comment: If Client_ID is your primary key (?), then the table already has a row with a "2" in it. Google for "identity column" and then use one of those.  So you wouldn't then specify the Client_ID in your insert statement.

Comment: Sorry I guess I wasn't clear. For example if the next record I try to enter is Client_ID 4 .... once it runs through the code, the record does not show up in the table, if I run the code again keeping 4 as the Client_ID it will throw the exception. It is like the data is there but not showing in the table.

Comment: You just need to refresh your data after the insert, it will be there.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it on another machine. This just isn't working. LOL folks are giving me negative votes so I will move on.

Comment: If you have a transaction that you haven't committed yet it will not show up in other sessions until you do commit it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute your command. i.e.

```
 // 3. Pass the connection to a command object
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Client_Master(Client_ID, Client_First, Client_Last) VALUES('2', 'Joe', 'Shmoe')", conn);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MASTER_TRANSACTION.Commit();
```

Check here for more info.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the SQL command.  Try

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the command but not doing anything with it. You're missing a:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, you should think of encapsulating the connection with a using statement, as it disposes it automatically, like:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a "catch" block to the "try" and "finally" so you can see if there is an error occurring.

Currently, you are missing the actually execution of the statement.  Add the following to fix that:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In addition, why are you using a Transaction?  Transactions are useful when executing multiple statements to ensure an "all or none" execution.  You are just inserting one row.

Answer (score 1):

your cmd is:

```
INSERT INTO Client_Master(Client_ID, Client_First, Client_Last) 
                   VALUES('2', 'Joe', 'Shmoe').
```

and i think that problem is here. with Client_ID column. You have set this column as primary key. but you are going to insert '2' in every time. for this reason it gives you

```
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was caught Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY
 constraint 'PK_Client_Master'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object dbo.Client_Master.
```

you can make Client_ID column as autoincrement

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is the record never gets inserted into the table. I only get that error during the same debug session. If I stop debugging and run it again, the first time through it runs fine. If I hit the button again I get the error. But at no point does the record ever actually get inserted into the record. So I am stumped. but I appreciate your input.